# Checking consistency of answers within groups (e.g. household) in R

Tags: r, survey, consistency

I got some survey data, in which the respondents answered various questions about environmental conditions on a 1-5 Likert scale. The respondents are also assigend to a household by an household ID. So e.g. there are 1 person living in household A, 3 persons in household B, 2 person in household C, 1 person in household D, etc.

Now I would like to check, whether the answers to the questions about environmental conditions are consistent within households. Or at least if it's more likely for persons living within a household to give the same (or a similar) rating on environmental conditions than people living in different households. (The hypothesis behind this is that people living in the same household should face similar conditions).

But I am kinda stuck on how to test that (in R)... any ideas/advice? :)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches that you can use:

1. Compare the proportion of variance within an between groups - this is called the intra-class correlation (ICC). An intraclass correlation of 1 means that there is no variance within a group (all the members of the group agree) and there is variance between groups.  An ICC of zero means that there is as much variance within groups as between groups - a person is no more likely to give a similar answer as someone in their household as they would be to someone outside their household.
2. Use some flavor of Cohen's Kappa - which assesses the extent to which agreement is greater than would be expected by chance. (E.g. if everyone has a 90% chance of saying 'yes' then you expect 82% agreement by chance - 82% agreement would therefore be a kappa of 0, representing only chance agreement.

There are several packages for calculating each of these. Use your favorite search engine.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, thank you very much for your answer!
That's already helpful, but I still struggle to apply any of the functions in the various packages to my problem.

I want to answer the following question: Is agreement on e.g. level of air pollution (rated on a one 1 to 5) higher within households than in the whole sample?

Could you provide me with a small code example with any of the suitable packages (e.g. the ICC package)?

I don't get where to specify the groups it should compare (household IDs) and which variable to test on (air pollution)...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, I made some progress now. The samplesize4survey package (https://cran.r-project.org/package=samplesize4surveys) offers an ICC function that allowed me to do what I wanted (it almost seems to easy to do it with that package, haha).

However, I also want to check for a binominal factor variable ("good" / "bad") whether responses within households are more consistant than in the whole sample population, which isn't possible using the ISS function. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Can you provide some example data? The binomial is trickier, but still possible.